# Which sensors can be used to feel breeze blowing by the robot?

Tags: force-sensor

Am faced with a situation where my robot needs to feel breeze blowing by over its artificial skin. While there exist many types of tactile sensors, nothing seems to fit the bill. I might abandon the idea altogether but just wanted to know for the sake of know how if there exist sensors to do this sort of thing. Given significant advances in MEMS/NEMS, am assuming there are sensors as sensitive or even more sensitive than hair follicles in detecting touch

Comment: Why are you looking at tactile sensors for sensing pressure? Are you specifically wanting to combine tactile sensing with sensing the air flow bear the skin?

Comment: What level of sensitivity do you require?

Comment: @Adam preferably as good as humans/animals....if possible even better

Answer (score 1):

Microphone chips have been used as a transducer for this due to their low cost. (This being high density pressure measurements)

Comment: Thanks hauptmech that's actually clever....am building a robot to observe physics at work and establish relationships over time. For example when it feels the wind while simultaneously watching leaves of the tree flutter and also hear it rustle, it should conclude that it's due to the breeze..........True AI can't be possible without good sense of smell, taste and touch am assuming

Comment: `For example when it feels the wind while simultaneously watching leaves of the tree flutter and also hear it rustle, it should conclude that it's due to the breeze.` .... this may not be a realistic goal ..... a dog has more intelligence that your robot can ever have, yet a dog is unaware that leaves rustling and fluttering is due to wind (i have two dogs and i'm pretty sure about what i said) ...... also, what should the robot conclude if it is windy and it sees a water fountain or a flock of birds?

Comment: @jsotola I know a dog is way more intelligent than my robot. In fact my robot is no match for a cockroach. The "rustling leaves" thing is intended for use at a very advanced stage. What I realised is while the problem of solving intelligence is hard enough, the bummer is that good hardware(sensors) does not exist yet. Animal ear and nose have high levels of sensitivity able to distinguish and amplify extremely minute changes. Good artificial noses, tongues and skin are still unsolved and still many researchers are trying for AGI